# what's wrong with my button in android make application stop working

Tags: java, android

`portText` to `CONTEXT(this)` contains some error. So if I comment it and app run correctly but no button shown in interface. What's wrong?

```
    private static Context CONTEXT;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
      /*portText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.portText);
       ipText=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.ipText);
       goBut=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.goBut);
       forBut=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.forBut);
       backBut=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.backBut);
       leftBut=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.leftBut);
       rightBut=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.rightBut);
       kickBut=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.kickBut);
       goBut.setOnClickListener(this);
       forBut.setOnClickListener(this);
       backBut.setOnClickListener(this);
       leftBut.setOnClickListener(this);
       rightBut.setOnClickListener(this);
       accText.setText("AccelerometerStatus ");
       CONTEXT(this); */

   }
```

Comment: Please format the code using indentation.

Comment: For all that I normally move it into one method setConnections()---what does logcat tell you the line that causes the error is?

Comment: Please post your logcat containing the error.

Comment: logcat 11-23 11:38:02.889: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button

Comment: which button gives you error ?

Comment: please debug the app;lication , apply break point at every line , move line by line and at every line clear your log cat , just when the exception comes , copy the logcat and post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the code

```
accText.setText("AccelerometerStatus ");
```

Where is accText initialized? If not then it is null

Comment: logcat 11-23 11:38:02.889: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button

Comment: hmm so it seems its casting wrong type, are you sure it is Imagebutton not Button? you need to post the xml so we can help you

Comment: one of my xml button
<Button
        android:id="@+id/forBut"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"

        android:background="@color/Butcolor"

        android:text="@string/Maju" />

Comment: You declare `forBut` as `Button`, but you are casting it to `ImageButton` in the line `forBut=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.forBut);`. Moreover, as @Snake mention, you will get NullPointerException because you have not yet instantiated `accText` before you call `setText`.

Comment: application run after i change imagebutton to button and delete accText.setText("AccelerometerStatus ");

thx all :D